# Implementing variables in public class

Tags: php, oop

```
class booking_diary {

    $start_timeS="09:30";
    $bookingS_start_time= "19:00";
    $bookingS_frequency=30;`enter code here`



    public $booking_start_time   =$start_timeS ;    // The time of the first slot in  
    public $booking_end_time =$bookingS_start_time; // The time of the last slot in  
    public $booking_frequency= $bookingS_frequency;  // The slot frequency per hour,
```

Can I do this?

Comment: Try it?! What is your question?¨

Comment: Why not try it yourself?.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't place custom code (here for your variables) inside a class-block.

If you wan't to init your class fields, you can use the class constructor

```
<?php
class booking_diary {

    public $booking_start_time;
    public $booking_end_time;
    public $booking_frequency;

    public function __construct() {
        $start_timeS="09:30";
        $bookingS_start_time= "19:00";
        $bookingS_frequency=30;
        //`enter code here`

        $this->booking_start_time = $start_timeS;
        $this->booking_end_time = $bookingS_start_time;
        $this->booking_frequency = $bookingS_frequency;
    }
}
```

If you want to feed the class with vars from outside, maybe something like this will fit your needs:

```
<?php
class booking_diary {

    public $booking_start_time;
    public $booking_end_time;
    public $booking_frequency;

    public function __construct($booking_start_time, $booking_end_time, $booking_frequency) {
        $this->booking_start_time = $booking_start_time;
        $this->booking_end_time = $booking_end_time;
        $this->booking_frequency = $booking_frequency;
    }
}

// Somewhere in your code:

$start_timeS="09:30";
$bookingS_start_time= "19:00";
$bookingS_frequency=30;
//`enter code here`

$instance = new booking_diary($start_timeS, $bookingS_start_time, $bookingS_frequency);
```

Comment: Why shouldn't OP be able to? He's just initialize the class property's.

Comment: @Rizier123 without a keyword (like `var`, `public`...) it is not a class property definition!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but what i want to do is, i have an input fields which i want the id's values to initialize the class booking_diary public variables.